# is this given language in class P?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, automata, complexity-classes

i was wondering:

is this language in class P?

$NONDISJOINT_{DFA}\:=\:\left\{<A,B> |\:A\:and\:B\:are\:DFAS\:and\:L\left(A\right)\:\cap L\left(b\right)\:\ne \varnothing \right\}$

explanation: a word $<A,B>$ belongs to the language if A and B are descriptions of finite deterministic automatas that the languages they identify are not foreign to each other

so in order to be in class P, the given language needs to be "solved" by a deterministic turing machine in polynomial time.

i tried to research this language but did not came with anything and i am not sure how to build simple algorithm(turing machine) that runs on both and verifies that there is at least common element and then maybe prove in induction for the rest. but that seems not very efficient.

i know that if $L(A)=L(B)$ then i can just build a turing machine that goes over the DFA. and if one is contained in the other, so i do a union of that DFAS and then i can build a turing machine that goes over both, but i am sure i am missing a lot of things and this is not a formal proof.

would really appreciate your help with this

Comment: There are two steps. Construct $C$, a DFA such that $L(C)=L(A)\cap L(B)$. Compute whether at least of one of the final states of $C$ is reachable.

Comment: ... and to add to what @Apass.Jack said, both constructions are standard and should be in any good theory text.